# SAPUI5 TypeScript Error: Extending @sapui5/types Component Interface

Tags: typescript, sapui5

*This issue is related to TypeScript, but I believe seeking help from the SAPUI5 community might lead to a solution.*

I'm working on a SAPUI5 project with Typescript, and I have the `@sapui5/types` package installed as a dev dependency. I have a function called `getContentDensityClass()` defined in my `Component.ts` file as follows:

```js
// webapp/Component.ts

public getContentDensityClass() {
    // ...
    return this._sContentDensityClass;
}
```

In my `App.controller.ts`, I want to use this function like this:

```js
// webapp/controller/App.controller.ts

public onMessagePopoverPress(oEvent: Event) {
    // ...
    syncStyleClass(this.getView()
                   .getController()
                   .getOwnerComponent()
                   .getContentDensityClass(), // here is the error
                   this.getView(),
                   oMessagePopover);
    // ...
}
```

However, TypeScript raises the following error:

- `getContentDensityClass does not exist on getOwnerComponent of type Component`

To address this issue, I tried extending the Component type from @sapui5/types as shown below:

```js
declare module "@sapui5/types" {
    export interface Component {
        getContentDensityClass(): string;
    }
}
```

Despite this attempt, the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

`getOwnerComponent` returns the generic UI5 component class. However, your custom method `getContentDensityClass` is defined in your custom component class.

You should assert the type of `getOwnerComponent`, for example:

```
import AppComponent from "../Component" // path to your Component.ts;

...

(this.getView()
   .getController()
   .getOwnerComponent() as AppComponent)
   .getContentDensityClass()
```

If you don't want to do this every time I'd suggest you put this in your BaseController

```
import AppComponent from "../Component";

getOwnerComponent(): AppComponent {
    return super.getOwnerComponent() as AppComponent;
}
```

Then your original code should work without any modification.